# Photo galleries for profile photos

Tags: layout, icons, faceted-search

Has anyone seen or can anyone envision a good way to sort many (50+) photos which are profile photos of staff members?

This is different from a traditional photo gallery because the emphasis isn't on the photo (i.e. we don't want it to zoom when clicked). Rather, choosing a photo lets you learn more about that person through there bio info that they've provided.

Furthermore, with 50+ photos, there should be an easy way to filter, (i.e. I only want to see people in finance, or finance and administration, or people who've been here for 3+ years).

Major kudos if this has already been implemented or can easily be forked from an existing app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to apply the **faceted navigation pattern** to a photo gallery. Take a look at the [Quince UI patterns library](http://quince.infragistics.com/html/PatternView.aspx?name=Faceted%20Navigation) for some examples of how this would play out. The Epicurious recipe browser looks a lot like what you're looking for, though instead of people's photos, they are glamour shots of food ;-). It allows the user to select the facets they want to apply to filter the gallery (years of service, department affiliation), and the content pane displays the refreshed photos based on their filter selections. Here's a screen shot:

[image]

As in your description, the photos are not the most important part of this pattern; they are another data point that would assist the user in recognizing their colleague and deciding if they want to learn more by clicking on their profile.

Comment: Great! Despite the prevalence of this design pattern, I don't see any good leads for implementing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not an implementer... I'm sure someone on stackoverflow would know of a configurable faceted search. Post the question and I'll upvote it!